# 4K screen set to 1920x1080 but still locked at 30Hz

Tags: graphics-card, resolution

I recently bought a 4K screen but my graphic card (Nvidia Geforce 710 GT) is not able to properly display a 4K-60Hz, so for the moment would like to set the screen resolution to 1920x1080 in order to come back to 60Hz refresh rate.

The problem is that I am still locked at 30Hz and even if the option seems to be possible, I get an error message while trying to set the refresh rate to 60Hz:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/85k9D.png

I tried to reinstall my drivers but nothing changed.

Comment: How are you connecting the monitor to the PC/graphics card (DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI)? According to their specs, that card can support 3840 x 2160 at 60 Hz on either HDMI or DisplayPort.

Comment: The website is wrong, I realized it displays different spec for the same item depending on the machine you use to visit the website, I don't know why (screenshot using my tower or my laptop, one of them also tells it's 60Hz compatible and the other 30Hz) https://i.imgur.com/1NHRzPy.png

Anyway I managed to solve the problem, it was because of the Wacom (drawing tablet with screen), I don't know why but having it plugged in locks the frame rate to 30fps even at 1920x1080 with the tablet turned off.